# Common practise for first-time questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette, comments

What is the common practise for commenting users with their first questions?

Maybe some links (something except faq?). Or useful answers on Meta site.

Comment: What do you mean by "commenting users with their first questions"? Are you talking about leaving comments on the first question asked by a new user to welcome them to the site?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about that.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any common practice. If you would like to leave a comment welcoming a new user to the site, that's fine, but it's not obligated or expected.